# Batch to remove everything before specified character on each line from text file

Tags: windows

We have requirement to remove all contects of each line before specified character from text file;

For Example we have below contents in test file;

```
sahdj232$This is 1st line
sdsdsadsa$This is 2nd line
sdasds$This is 3rd line
```

Now by giving above file name as input to batch file we want file to have below contents;

```
$This is 1st line
$This is 2nd line
$This is 3rd line
```

Here we want to remove all which lies before '$' in text file.

Can somebody help.

Answer (score 2):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
(
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=$" %%a IN (q28692650.txt) DO ECHO($%%b
)>newfile.txt

TYPE newfile.txt

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q28692650.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces newfile.txt

Simply, for each line in the file, split the line into two tokens using `$` as delimiters. Put the first token (the part before `$`) in `%%a` and the remainder of the line (*) in `%%b`. Then echo $ and `%%b`

Answer (score -1):

Read the file content in a variable, then use following expression, assuming content of file has been loaded in toClean variable:

```js
var toClean = "sahdj232$This is 1st line\nsdsdsadsa$This is 2nd line\nsdasds$This is 3rd line";
var split = toClean.split(/[\n$]+/);
var clean = '';

for(var i = 0, len = split.length; i < len; i++){
    var index = 2 * i + 1;
    if( split[index] !== undefined ){
        clean += '$' + split[index];
    }
}

console.log(clean);
```

Will only work if pair number of $ in your content. Otherwise you could use a regexp.

Comment: I tried code given by you. But unfortunately its not in valid syntax for windows batch files.